# pyodbc error: unixODBC can't open Microsoft ODBC driver, running on Apache RHEL

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pyodbc, unixodbc

Trying to port my proof-of-concept, Python-driven web page (which is currently hosted on my Windows 7 laptop running IIS) to a LAMP setup on the Amazon cloud. From my Amazon EC2 RHEL6 server, my pyodbc calls are failing when my Python modules are called by Apache, although I can run the same modules myself from the command line and they return data from my SQL-Server-based RDS server as designed.

I started with a clean RHEL 6 install, then installed unixODBC, the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11, and pyodbc. My Python modules are installed in /var/www/cgi-bin. I have a "hello.py" module there as well, which I can successfully invoke from the Web. But when my browser runs the Python with the pyodbc call, I get a 500 error and the following Python stack trace in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:

```
[Tue Nov 19 13:09:31 2013] [error] [client 108.41.105.79] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Nov 19 13:09:31 2013] [error] [client 108.41.105.79]   File "/var/www/cgi-bin/emit_message_count_timeline.py", line 92, in <module>
[Tue Nov 19 13:09:31 2013] [error] [client 108.41.105.79]
[Tue Nov 19 13:09:31 2013] [error] [client 108.41.105.79] date_end=date_end, loco_id=loco_id, normalized=normalized)
[Tue Nov 19 13:09:31 2013] [error] [client 108.41.105.79]   File "/var/www/cgi-bin/emit_message_count_timeline.py", line 19, in emit_message_count_timeline
[Tue Nov 19 13:09:31 2013] [error] [client 108.41.105.79]     date_end=date_end, loco_id=loco_id, normalized=normalized)
[Tue Nov 19 13:09:31 2013] [error] [client 108.41.105.79]   File "/var/www/cgi-bin/ServeChartData.py", line 617, in query_message_count_timeline
[Tue Nov 19 13:09:31 2013] [error] [client 108.41.105.79]     conn = create_db_connection()
[Tue Nov 19 13:09:31 2013] [error] [client 108.41.105.79]   File "/var/www/cgi-bin/ServeChartData.py", line 42, in create_db_connection
[Tue Nov 19 13:09:31 2013] [error] [client 108.41.105.79]     conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_string)
[Tue Nov 19 13:09:31 2013] [error] [client 108.41.105.79] pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-11.0.so.2270.0' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
[Tue Nov 19 13:09:31 2013] [error] [client 108.41.105.79] Premature end of script headers: emit_message_count_timeline.py
```

The ODBC driver should be callable by any user:

```
[ec2-user@(...)]$ ls -l /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-11.0.so.2270.0
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 1757680 Nov 15 15:37 /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-11.0.so.2270.0
```

UPDATE 2013-11-20:

```
[ec2-user@(...) ~]$ cat /etc/odbcinst.ini
[ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-11.0.so.2270.0
Threading=1
UsageCount=1
```

UPDATE 2013-11-21: All of the driver's dependencies seem to be intact:

```
[ec2-user@domU-12-31-39-09-4A-9D tmp]$ ldd /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-11.0.so.2270.0
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff736a7000)
libcrypto.so.10 => /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10 (0x00007feacdaa2000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007feacd89e000)
librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007feacd695000)
libssl.so.10 => /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10 (0x00007feacd438000)
libuuid.so.1 => /lib64/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007feacd234000)
libodbcinst.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libodbcinst.so.1 (0x00007feacd01c000)
libkrb5.so.3 => /lib64/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007feaccd36000)
libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007feaccaf2000)
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007feacc7eb000)
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007feacc567000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007feacc351000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007feacc133000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007feacbda0000)
libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007feacbb8a000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00000034f0c00000)
libcom_err.so.2 => /lib64/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007feacb985000)
libk5crypto.so.3 => /lib64/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007feacb759000)
libkrb5support.so.0 => /lib64/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007feacb54e000)
libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007feacb34a000)
libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007feacb130000)
libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007feacaf10000)
```

EDIT 2013-12-02:
In case it helps, here's an oddity. In my Apache config file, /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf, I am setting the following two environment variables:

```
SetEnv LD_LIBRARY_PATH  /lib64:/usr/lib64:/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64
SetEnv LIBPATH          /lib64:/usr/lib64:/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64
```

but when I write a simple Python CGI script to to print out all the environment variables, of these two I see only LIBPATH:

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os

print "Content-type: text/plain"
print        
print "Hello, world of Apache Python"

for key in sorted(os.environ.iterkeys()):
    print key, os.environ[key]
```

Output in my browser (blank line and all):

```
Hello, world of Apache Python
DOCUMENT_ROOT /opt/cosmalogs/www
GATEWAY_INTERFACE CGI/1.1
HTTP_ACCEPT text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING gzip,deflate,sdch
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE en-US,en;q=0.8
HTTP_CONNECTION keep-alive
HTTP_HOST ec2-107-22-64-71.compute-1.amazonaws.com
HTTP_USER_AGENT Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.57 Safari/537.36
LIBPATH /lib64:/usr/lib64:/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64
PATH /sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
QUERY_STRING 
REMOTE_ADDR 184.75.42.178
REMOTE_PORT 4765
REQUEST_METHOD GET
REQUEST_URI /cgi-bin/hello.py
SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/cgi-bin/hello.py
SCRIPT_NAME /cgi-bin/hello.py
SERVER_ADDR 10.236.176.197
SERVER_ADMIN root@localhost
SERVER_NAME ec2-107-22-64-71.compute-1.amazonaws.com
SERVER_PORT 80
SERVER_PROTOCOL HTTP/1.1
SERVER_SIGNATURE <address>Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) Server at ec2-107-22-64-71.compute-1.amazonaws.com Port 80</address>

SERVER_SOFTWARE Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat)
```

EDIT 2013-12-05: I am not really sure the cause of the problem, but running strace with the -f option to include forked (child) processes, I may have traced the problem to the following lines in the child process that is presumably Python. It doesn't explain why Python is reporting "file not found," however:

```
[pid  2006] open("/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-11.0.so.2270.0", O_RDONLY) = 3
[pid  2006] read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\340$\2\0\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\260\312\32\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\0008\0\6\0@\0\35\0\34\0\1\0\0\0\5\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\350\347\30\0\0\0\0\0\350\347\30\0\0\0\0\0\0\0 \0\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0\6\0\0\0\350\347\30\0\0\0\0\0\350\3478\0\0\0\0\0\350\3478\0\0\0\0\0l\341\1\0\0\0\0\0\240B\2\0\0\0\0\0\0\0 \0\0\0\0\0\2\0\0\0\6\0\0\0\210\310\31\0\0\0\0\0\210\3109\0\0\0\0\0\210\3109\0\0\0\0\0@\2\0\0\0\0\0\0@\2\0\0\0\0\0\0\10\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\220\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\220\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\220\1\0\0\0\0\0\0$\0\0\0\0\0\0\0$\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\0\0\0\0P\345td\4\0\0\0\2200\27\0\0\0\0\0\2200\27\0\0\0\0\0\2200\27\0\0\0\0\0<<\0\0\0\0\0\0<<\0\0\0\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\0\0\0\0Q\345td\6\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\10\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\4\0\0\0\24\0\0\0\3\0\0\0GNU\0\372N\2K\251&{\230\244\272@\255f\3a\270t\352\377\231\0\0\0\0a\0\0\0\1\1\0\0\20\0\0\0\n\0\0\0\0 P\10 \1\0\0\0\204\10 \200\0\20\0\200\0\10\205\rP\0\250\24\4\260@\0\20\0\250\6A\206\0@\0\2\0h\200\6\0\200\0\2\0\224\"\300!\t 0\211\2\0\4\21\2\300\201\f\4\201\t\200\0\20\300\1\10\240\24h\2\242X$\2\0\200\2\0\1\20\20\240\200\20h\30\10\10\10*H%\304\20\23@Y\0\260\300\4\0\30@@\1\10\4\0\200\0\0\t\0\20\0N\22\206\220\204\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\5\1\0\0\6\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\10\1\0\0\n\1\0\0\v\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\f\1\0\0\r\1\0\0\17\1\0\0\20\1\0\0\21\1\0\0\22\1\0\0\24\1\0\0\26\1\0\0\27\1\0\0\30\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\31\1\0\0\33\1\0\0\35\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\37\1\0\0\0\0\0\0 \1\0\0!\1\0\0#\1\0\0%\1\0\0&\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0(\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0*\1\0\0+\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0-\1\0\0/\1\0\0001\1\0\0004\1\0\0006\1\0\0007\1\0\0009\1\0\0:\1\0\0<\1\0\0=\1\0\0>\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0@\1\0\0A\1\0\0B\1\0\0C\1\0\0", 832) = 832
[pid  2006] fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1757680, ...}) = 0
[pid  2006] mmap(NULL, 3877512, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
[pid  2006] close(3)                    = 0
```

Thank you for any help! 
BH

Comment: What does your `/etc/odbc.ini` file look like? And your connection string in Python?

Comment: /etc/odbc.ini is empty. The connection string looks like:

    conn_string = "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server};SERVER=(censored).cnl9pinhfcef.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com,1433;DATABASE=(censored);" \
    "UID=stackoverflow_angel;PWD=help_buzzy;"

Comment: I'm not familiar with RedHat (too many years since I used it) but it seems like on one of my Ubuntu installations I had to create a link in /usr/lib even though `odbcinst.ini` had the correct location. You might try `ln -s /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-11.0.so.2270.0 /usr/lib64/libmsodbcsql-11.0.so.2270.0` and see if that works. Sorry I'm not more helpful Buzzy.

Comment: Benny, thanks for your suggestion. I verified and ran the command exactly as you suggested, then restarted the httpd service. Unfortunately, no difference.

Comment: Try running the web server from the command line under strace, then look through the log generated whe you try and call your script and search for the code trying to load the driver lib, from that point on you can see what it loads and where it looks.

Comment: Thanks @Nick. I ran "sudo strace -f -s 2048 -p 1302" on the PID of the single httpd process, and I may have narrowed the problem to a mmap call following a successful open of the driver file, /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-11.0.so.2270.0. I've appended my post with what I think is the relevant excerpt.